# What will parse do to the deleted PFFile?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pffile

I uploaded a PFFile to Parse.com, and saved the url of the PFFile. Then I deleted the PFFile, and tried using the saved url to download the PFFile. It's success!

So my question is: What will Parse.com do to the deleted PFFile? Is the PFFile being saved permanently or will be deleted in some time?

Comment: Parse is one type of database  you can store life time PFFile or permanent PFFile? Nothing is impossible in parse database.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'd like confirm that even if I deleted the PFFile, the PFFile will  still be exist in that original url?

Comment: You should be able to delete a file using the PFFile class in code, a strange omission! Please add this functionality, I shouldn't have to add a REST interface or occasionally press a clean up button!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this question/answer there is no way to permanently delete these files without doing it manually or through the REST API: https://www.parse.com/questions/deleting-pffiles

The 2 ways you can do it are:

1. Go to the "Clean up Files" (Settings/Clean up Files) button on your app's dashboard to delete all of the files.
2. Use the REST API:

   curl -X DELETE \
           -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: " \
           -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: " \
           https://api.parse.com/1/files/

The last option is only good for deleting one file, so the first choice looks like the best here. It's unfortunate that you cannot do this using the SDK, but it is a good security measure as Files do not have ACLs.